# How can I use SeekBar's OnSeekBarChangeListener to seek to a specific point in a MediaPlayer object?

Tags: android

I have some Android code to stream an audio file from the internet and play the stream after 10 seconds.

I am using a SeekBar to view the buffering status and playing status. I want to play the audio starting from the middle of the buffered stream. For that, I move the SeekBar point to the middle, but I cannot play the audio from the middle; it will go back and start from the beginning. How can I get the seeked position and how can I play the audio from that particular position?

Here is my SeekBar code. How can I make this code use the OnSeekBarChangeListener properly?

```
seekbar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new OnSeekBarChangeListener() {

    @Override
    public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar arg0, int arg1, boolean arg2) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (arg2 && mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
            //myProgress = oprogress;
            arg1=mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition();
            mediaPlayer.seekTo(arg1);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
arg1=mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition();
mediaPlayer.seekTo(arg1);
```

You are forcing the player to seek to the current position, and not to the positon retuned by the Seekbar

Remove the line: `arg1=mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition();` and it should work. Of course after `MediaPlayer.prepare()` set `SeekBar.setMax(MediaPlayer.getDuration())`, so seeking will be accurate.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to make a thread... I have some code given below which you can try to implement.

```
public void run() {
    try
    {
        while(song1.getDuration()!=song1.getCurrentPosition())
        {
            skbar.setProgress(song1.getCurrentPosition());
            //bStop.setText(song1.getCurrentPosition());
        }
        if (song1.getDuration()==song1.getCurrentPosition())
            Log.v("log","Sanket");
        t.suspend();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Log.e("log",e.toString());
    }
}
```